# How to add after selected row in tableview?

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have selected row, and I need to add some data right below it. Row is selected with `OrderTable selectedOrderTable = orderTableId.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();` and new one is added with `data.add(new OrderTable( ... ))` It's adding OK to table, just at bottom of it, and I need to add it right below selected row `selectedOrderTable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call the [`add` method taking an index](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-):

```
int index = orderTableId.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
data.add(index + 1, new OrderTable(...));
```